# Opencart v 2.3 create module from another module

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, opencart-module, opencart2.3

on opencart v2.3 I did create a module from manufacturer

I created a table on mysql similar to manufacturer table and I duplicated this files

> admin/controller/catalog/manufacturer.php
>
> admin/language/en-gb/catalog/manufacturer.php
>
> admin/model/catalog/manufacturer.php
>
> admin/view/template/catalog/manufacturer_form.tpl
>
> admin/view/template/catalog/manufacturer_list.tpl

and changed manufacturer to enchere and also inside the files i changed manufacturer to enchere and the class names too

> admin/controller/catalog/enchere.php
>
> admin/language/en-gb/catalog/enchere.php
>
> admin/model/catalog/enchere.php
>
> admin/view/template/catalog/enchere_form.tpl
>
> admin/view/template/catalog/enchere_list.tpl

but when i uploaded the files to my opencart in the same folders where manufacturer are I didn't see no where enchere

can someone help me plz

Comment: What happens when you trying to access:
http://yoursite.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/enchere
?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to System>Users>User Groups>Edit to your group then give access to the new module, you can do a small search to be sure search for catalog/enchere you will find it unselected, once you select it it will appear.